# CASE Statement with more than two columns need to be equal

Tags: sql-server

I am still fairly new to SQL Server 2008 and have a question about a CASE statement. 
I have three different columns for three different databases, and I need to see the variance in quantities between the three. Everything else in my query works fine, now I just need to add this CASE statement. When I use two columns (A=B), the CASE works just fine. But I'm not sure how to add the third in. Below is what I have, but it tells me "Incorrect Syntax near '='." All of the fields are numeric and may or may not have different quantities. I just need to have something flag me when at least one of the quantities is off. Any suggestions? :) Thank you.

```
,CASE WHEN ColumnA = ColumnB = ColumnC THEN 'N'
ELSE 'Y'
END AS 'Variance Y/N'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Case Statement` you cannot use two [`Comparison Operators`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188074.aspx) without having a `logical operator` in between them. Try like this..

```
  CASE
     WHEN ColumnA = ColumnB
          AND ColumnB = ColumnC THEN 'N'
     ELSE 'Y'
   END AS 'Variance Y/N'
```

Comment: You don't need the third and.  If a=b and b=c then a always equals c.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp12
(
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT,
    col3 int
)

INSERT INTO #tmp12 ( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES  (1,2,3 )
INSERT INTO #tmp12 ( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES  (1,1,1 )


SELECT (CASE WHEN col1 = col2 AND col1 = col3 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END) FROM #tmp12
```